# Female to female 1/2 " angle adapter

Tags: socket

I need to have a special adapter that is formed by connecting two 3/8 " to 1/2 " adapters at 90 degrees angle. I want both ends of the adapter to be females only.

I have two of these:

[image]

And I want to attach them together like this without welding:

[image]

Is there any official adapter on the market to do it for me? Do I have to make one?

It is hard to find a L-shaped piece of metal and drill square holes on both ends of it.

=============================

@HandyHowie

As promised, I returned with pictures and more info. You asked about what I have done with my Allen key and two sockets.

These are my two 10 mm sockets and a 10 mm Allen key:

[image]

I connected the sockets to both ends of the Allen like this:

[image]

This is my torque wrench and a 1/2 " extension bar:

[image]

Now I connect the extension bar to the square drive of my torque wrench to form a long extension:

[image]

[image]

However, the above extension bar was just an example for demonstration purposes. I have another L-shaped extension bar that I want to connect to the torque wrench with the same method.

This is my L-shaped 1/2 " extension bar which I want to attach to my torque wrench:

[image]

Why I don't use this Allen Key method? Because the sockets need to be welded to Allen Key and I prefer to use welding as the last resort.

This way I can increase the torque and the following formula (which is offered by torque wrench manufacturers themselves) help me to know how much more torque I will apply to the fastener in each torque setting.

[image]

[image]

For instance, my torque wrench is 0.36 meter long. Without extension I need to apply **22.66 kg** to its handle to produce **80 nm** of torque. With my extension (0.42 meter + 0.10 meter the length of Allen Key = 0.52 meter), I need to apply only **9.27 kg** to my torque wrench to produce the same **80 nm**.

The main benefit of the extension is that it increases the maximum torque capacity of my torque wrench.

My torque wrench supports a range of between 15 and 80 nm. My lug nuts require 90 nm which exceeds my torque wrench capacity. With the extension, I need to set my torque wrench to 37 nm to produce 90 nm!

Comment: Can you describe its use?  You clearly don’t want to use it for a socket set.

Comment: @HandyHowie - I have a long L-shaped extension bar and I want to connect it to my torque wrench to form something like a crowfoot. I need a 90 degree turn to connect the torque wrench to the extension bar. One easy solution I have found is to use two 10 mm 1/2 " sockets and attach both to the ends of a 10 mm Allen key and finally connect one end to the torque wrench and the other to the bar. However, I'm looking for better solutions.

Comment: Surely your torque wrench won’t be calibrated for doing something like that will it?  Maybe I am not understanding you fully.  Can you add a photo of what you currently have set up with the Allen key?

Comment: @HandyHowie - Sure. I will take some pictures and come back to you soon with more info. Torque wrenches are not calibrated for extensions (like crowfoot) but if you add them to the square drive of the torque wrench (not the handle), it is always possible to calculate the increased torque with some simple calculations through formulas which are available at torque wrench manufacturers' websites. https://www.norbar.com/Support/Calculators/Torque-Wrench-Extension-Formula#:~:text=When%20you%20put%20an%20extension,M1%20%3D%20M2%20x%20L1%20%2F%20L2

Comment: @HandyHowie - I provided the necessary information in pictures for you to fully understand my Allen Key idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Using a 1/2 inch swivel adapter, you can plug the male end into a regular 16mm 1/2 socket. Plug it into the nut side as shown, leaving a second female 1/2 at the other side of the socket.

It fits really solid - even though it does not look like it in the picture, so should withstand reasonable workload as long as you are not giving it the beans.

Update: It looks like you are just trying to get extra reach? Take a look at serpentine belt tools. The smaller part:

[image]

Can be used to extend length of torque wrench:

[image]

The interesting thing about this setup is that you can add regular extensions to add depth if needed. This may also be an option.

Comment: That was a genius idea. The only problem is that there is some variation in size between 1/2 " adapters and 16 mm sockets. Not all of them fit inside one another to form a nice and snug fit.

Comment: That serpentine belt tool is a good idea. I try to make something like that with steel profiles (Flat Stock).

Answer (score 1):

Buy a 90˚ plumbing ell in metal like this:

[image]

(image from images.google.com)

Find a machine shop or a welder. Have your two adapters welded into the ell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think using an Allen key is a better idea than plumbing because Allen key has a 90 degrees turn and it is also possible to connect two 1/2 " sockets to both ends of it. However, I'm seeking a non-welding solution for now.